# How to change the decimal format

Tags: c#

I want to change the decimal place separator
I changed the location, but it still does not change

Current result
100,200.00
expected result
100.200,00

```
item.currentAmount.ToString(string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N2}"));
```

Comment: What is with the `string.Format` inside `ToString`?

Comment: I'd expect something like: `item.currentAmount.ToString("{0:N2}", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) override method

> Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object)

Setting the culture on the first parameter.

```
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"),"{0:N2}",item.currentAmount)
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zudrXg)